# Why is my cursor and my line of draw are in diffrent sides?

Tags: javascript, css

I am attempting to create a drawing app in JS, however, whenever anything is drawn, it is positioned away from my cursor depending on where it is on the canvas, when I am on the furthest left/bottom side of the canvas, you can draw where your cursor is, but the further right/up I move, the more the brush begins to "drift" and go further than where my cursor is.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const increaseBtn = document.getElementById("increase");
const decreaseBtn = document.getElementById("decrease");
const sizeEl = document.getElementById("size");
const colorEl = document.getElementById("color");
const clearEl = document.getElementById("clear");

//Core Drawing Functionality (with some research)

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let size = 5;
let isPressed = false;
let color = "black";
let x;
let y;
let fakeSize = 1;

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  isPressed = true;
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
  isPressed = false;
  x = undefined;
  y = undefined;
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (isPressed) {
    const x2 = e.offsetX;
    const y2 = e.offsetY;

    drawCircle(x2, y2);
    drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);

    x = x2;
    y = y2;
  }
});

function drawCircle(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);

  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.lineWidth = size * 2;
  ctx.stroke();
}

function updateSizeOnScreen() {
  sizeEl.innerHTML = fakeSize;
}

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  size += 5;
  fakeSize++;
  if (fakeSize > 10) {
    fakeSize = 10;
  }

  if (size > 50) {
    size = 50;
  }

  updateSizeOnScreen();
});

decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  size -= 5;
  fakeSize--;
  if (fakeSize < 1) {
    fakeSize = 1;
  }

  if (size < 5) {
    size = 5;
  }

  updateSizeOnScreen();
});

colorEl.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  color = e.target.value;
});

clearEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});

//Eraser and Pencil Actions (my own algorithm)

const eraser = document.getElementById("eraser");
const pencil = document.getElementById("pencil");

eraser.addEventListener("click", () => {
  localStorage.setItem("colorEl", JSON.stringify(color));
  color = "#fff";
  colorEl.disabled = true;
  canvas.classList.add("eraseractive");
  eraser.classList.add("eraseractive");
  colorEl.classList.add("eraseractive");
  canvas.classList.remove("pencilactive");
  eraser.classList.remove("pencilactive");
  colorEl.classList.remove("pencilactive");
});

pencil.addEventListener("click", () => {
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("colorEl"));
  color = colorEl.value;
  colorEl.disabled = false;
  canvas.classList.remove("eraseractive");
  eraser.classList.remove("eraseractive");
  colorEl.classList.remove("eraseractive");
  canvas.classList.add("pencilactive");
  eraser.classList.add("pencilactive");
  colorEl.classList.add("pencilactive");
});

// Dark/Light Mode

const darkMode = document.getElementById("darkMode");
const lightMode = document.getElementById("lightMode");
const toolbox = document.getElementById("toolbox");

darkMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
  darkMode.classList.add("mode-active");
  lightMode.classList.remove("mode-active");
  lightMode.classList.add("rotate");
  darkMode.classList.remove("rotate");
  toolbox.style.backgroundColor = "#293462";
  document.body.style.backgroundImage =
    "url('/assets/images/darkModeBackground.svg')";

  document.body.style.backgroundSize = "1920px 1080px";
  canvas.style.borderColor = "#293462";
  toolbox.style.borderColor = "#293462";
});

lightMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
  lightMode.classList.add("mode-active");
  darkMode.classList.remove("mode-active");
  darkMode.classList.add("rotate");
  lightMode.classList.remove("rotate");
  toolbox.style.backgroundColor = "#293462";
  document.body.style.backgroundImage =
    "url('/assets/images/lightModeBackground.svg')";

  document.body.style.backgroundSize = "1920px 1080px";
  canvas.style.borderColor = "#293462";
  toolbox.style.borderColor = "#293462";
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

body {
  background: url("https://drawing-app-green.vercel.app/assets/images/lightModeBackground.svg");
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

::selection {
  background: transparent;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}

.mode {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.light-mode {
  color: yellow;
}

.dark-mode {
  color: #16213e;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #293462;
  cursor: url("https://drawing-app-green.vercel.app/assets/images/pencilCursor.png") 2 48, pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.toolbox {
  background-color: #293462;
  border: 1px solid #293462;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.toolbox > * {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toolbox > *:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

canvas.eraseractive {
  cursor: url("https://drawing-app-green.vercel.app/assets/images/eraserCursor.png") 2 48, pointer;
}

#color.eraseractive {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

canvas.pencilactive {
  cursor: url("https://drawing-app-green.vercel.app/assets/images/pencilCursor.png") 2 48, pointer;
}

.mode-active {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Drawing App</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-moon dark-mode fa-2x mode" id="darkMode"></i>
    <i
      class="fa-solid fa-sun light-mode fa-2x mode mode-active"
      id="lightMode"
    ></i>
    <div class="container">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="600"></canvas>
      <div class="toolbox" id="toolbox">
        <button id="decrease">-</button>
        <span id="size">1</span>
        <button id="increase">+</button>
        <input type="color" id="color" />
        <button id="pencil">
          <img src="assets/images/pencilCursor.png" alt="" />
        </button>
        <button id="eraser">
          <img src="assets/images/eraserCursor.png" alt="" />
        </button>
        <button id="clear">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try setting `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` to the dimensions of the element. You may try first with a constant value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your canvas dimentions don't match with the dimentions of the HTML element that contains it. You see: your canvas has a fixed width="" and height="" attributes set. But in your HTML your canvas element has a width of 100%. So that means that the container vairies in dimentions but the canvas inside it not. This result in the canvas trying to resize to show inside the container thus giving you issues with calculating exacly what pixel you are clicking.

You have two options:

**Option 1: calculate your click position taking into account canvas deformation**

If you want your canvas to resize, then calculate the real position using a simple ratio formula. If for example your canvas has a width of 100 but right now its container is 10px wide, then if you click on pixel 5 you expect a dot to be drawn at pixel 50. In other words if your canvas is smaller by a factor of 10 then you need to multiply your position by a factor of 10.

In your code it would look something like this:

```js
    // this is your same code in lines 33 ana34 but see that I added a multiplication by the ratio between the canvas size and the canvas container
    const x2 = e.offsetX * (canvas.width / ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    const y2 = e.offsetY * (canvas.height / ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

**Option #2: Dont allow your canvas to deform**

Remove the container class, and remove the width:100% from your canvas css. Your canvas will overflow and cause a scrollbar but the positions will be calculated properly with your code.